# Dealing with NaN's in matlab functions

Tags: r, matlab, function, matrix, nan

I was wondering if matlab has a built in way to deal with `NaN`'s in function calls.  More specifically, I am trying to take the mean of a vector that has a `NaN` in it.  For example, in R

```
> x = c(1,2,3,4,NA)
> mean(x)
[1] NA
> mean(x,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 2.5
```

Is there something comprable to this in Matlab that is in one line (I don't want to write my own function nor have to loop to find `NaN`'s before calculating the mean).

Also, I do not have access to the statistics toolbox so I can't use something like `nanmean()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like `mean(x(~isnan(x)))`. If you want you could also write a bunch of wrappers like this and put them in your startup.m file.

Answer (score 3):

As of MATLAB 2015a, [`mean` supports an extra parameter, `nanflag`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015a/matlab/ref/mean.html#inputarg_nanflag). Using the example from JoErNanO's answer,

```
A = [1 0 NaN; 0 3 4; 0 NaN 2];
mean(A, 'omitnan')
% = [0.333333333333333 1.5 3]
```

The default for that parameter is `includenan`, which will return `NaN` for columns/rows containing `NaN`s.

`median`, `cov`, `min`, `max`, `sum`, `var` and `std` also support ignoring of `NaN`s.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
mean(x(isfinite(x)));
```

Answer (score 2):

### What about Matrices?

As Karthik V suggests,

```matlab
mean(x(~isnan(x)))
```

will work for vectors. However in case you have an n-by-m matrix and wish to compute the row-/column-wise mean discarding occasional NaN's you will have to run a for loop.

### Sample Scenario

Imagine a data matrix of the form:

```matlab
A = [1 0 NaN; 0 3 4; 0 NaN 2]

A =
 1     0   NaN
 0     3     4
 0   NaN     2
```

Running `mean(A(~isnan(A)))` yields:

```matlab
ans =

1.4286
```

This is because the logical indexing effectively "flattens" the matrix into a vector.

### Looping Solution (Column-wise Mean)

Assuming you want to compute the column-wise mean, the looping solution then becomes:

```matlab
% Preallocate resulting mean vector
nCols = size(A, 2);
mu = zeros(1, nCols);

% Compute means
for col = 1:nCols
    mu(col) = mean(A(~isnan(A(:, col)), col));
end
```

Resulting in:

```matlab
mu =

0.3333    1.5000    3.0000
```

### Looping Solution (Row-wise Mean)

Assuming you want to compute the row-wise mean, the looping solution then becomes:

```matlab
% Preallocate resulting mean vector
nRows = size(A, 1);
mu = zeros(nRows, 1);

% Compute means
for row = 1:nRows
    mu(row) = mean(A(row, ~isnan(A(row, :))));
end
```

Resulting in:

```matlab
mu =

0.5000
2.3333
1.0000
```