# Taking the mean of a matrix with NaN's in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, nan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dealing with NaN’s in matlab functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693536/dealing-with-nans-in-matlab-functions)

Is there a one line command that allows you to take the elementwise average of a matrix (ignoring `NaN`'s) in Matlab?  For example,

```
>> A = [1 0 NaN; 0 3 4; 0 NaN 2]

A =

     1     0   NaN
     0     3     4
     0   NaN     2
```

So the `mean(A)` should equal `(1+3+2+4+0+0+0)/7 = 1.4286`

Also, I don't have access to the stats toolbox so I cannot use `nanmean()`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693536/dealing-with-nans-in-matlab-functions for a solution

Comment: As of version 2015a, there is a 'omitnan' flag that you can pass as the third parameter to mean to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`isnan()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html) to filter out the unwanted elements:

```
mean(A(~isnan(A)))
```

Comment: Doesn't `A(isnan(A))` return only the `NaN` elements? And are we missing a right parenthesis?

Comment: @Prashant: Already fixed!

Answer (score 2):

```
nanmean
```

Performs just like `mean`, but ignoring nans.

For example:

```
>> A = [1 0 NaN; 0 3 4; 0 NaN 2]
A =
     1     0   NaN
     0     3     4
     0   NaN     2
>> nanmean(A)
ans =
         0.333333333333333                       1.5                         3
>> nanmean(A,2)
ans =
                       0.5
          2.33333333333333
                         1
>> nanmean(A(:))
ans =
          1.42857142857143
```

Comment: Didn't notice your caveat about no stats toolbox until now.  Oli's answer is the right one.