# How to take the average of a 3D matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, mean

I have a (244,800,4) matrix as a .mat file. There are NaNs in each layer. How can I take an average of each of this layers.

So basically I need one average (of the entire layer) per layer.

Thanks

Comment: What have you come up with so far? Have you tried any code? Please define "layer"? Which dimension?

Comment: I did something like this
`PAR=mean(PAR(~isnan(PAR(:,:,1))));`
Which gives me the correct average for the first layer, However when I want to switch to the next layer 
`PAR=mean(PAR(~isnan(PAR(:,:,2))));`
It gives me NaN instead of any real value

Comment: possible duplicate of [Taking the mean of a matrix with NaN's in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694706/taking-the-mean-of-a-matrix-with-nans-in-matlab)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We found an easy way to the problem

```
for ii=1:4
 a=reshape(PAR(:,:,ii),1,[]);
 b(ii)=nanmean(a);
end
```

I used the reshape command. 
Thanks to Hanif Hosseini from Georgia Tech.

Comment: I already gave you a better way: `nanmean(reshape(PAR,[],size(PAR,3)))`

Answer (score 2):

`nanmean(nanmean(matrixname))` does the trick I think.

Answer (score 0):

I use `nanmean` for this, but it's part of the Statistics Toolbox.  If you don't have that, you need to roll your own.

You can split your layers into a cell array and remove NAN values on each.  Something like this:

```
Mcells = arrayfun( @(x) M(:,:,x), 1:size(M,3), 'uni', false );
Mmeans = cellfun( @(x) mean(x(~isnan(x(:)))), Mcells );
```

Comment: Note that `nanmean` is available also on the MATLAB File Exchange in the [NaN Suite](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6837-nan-suite). Not to say that they're implemented the same.

Comment: I have the `nanmean` package, however, I dont know how to point it to each single layer. I dont think it can anyway.

Comment: @FotacFotacy Try `nanmean(reshape(M,[],size(M,3)))`

Comment: @FotacFotacy - it DEFINITELY can. Read the help.

Comment: @woodchips not on its own - the OP wants to take the average across the first and second dimensions.  `nanmean` only operates across a single dimension, so you need to reshape the matrix first.

Comment: @ paddy, I did the same thing. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

`mean(mean(matrixName))` will give you a 1x1x4 matrix of the mean of each 'layer' in your matrix. You may want to do something to remove the NaNs though.

Comment: This is a good approach but I'm averaging twice so it introduces some errors into the calculations.